# Getting child node is not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the  tag in the below format. and when i get the child node It was not working in IE7 browser.

```
<map>
   <series1>
       <area></area>
       <area></area>
       <area></area>
    </series1>

   <series2>
       <area></area>
       <area></area>
       <area></area>
    </series2>
</map>
```

I want to get `<series1>` and `<series2>` child node. but in IE7 all child node is under `<map>` tag.

JS

```
$('map').children().size()
```

It will return all the child count including `<area>` tag only in IE7. but IE9 it return only `<series>` count. I am not able to get the series child node. I try the below code.

JS

```
$('series1').children('area').size();
```

But it returns the `zero` count.

any one could help me on this?

Thanks,

Bharathi.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Because [`size()` works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/uDA7c/1/), despite it being deprecated. (You should be using `length` property)

Comment: I guess IE<9 does not support custom tags so that might be causing issues.